# Desactivar Boton dependiendo del usuario

Tags: php, javascript, web

Estoy trabajando en php y mysql es una aplicacion web y tengo una base de datos con una tabla que se llama usuarios con los campos

- id_usuario
- nombre
- tipo_usuario
- password

Y en el tipo usuario solo pude haber dos que son ADMINISTRADOR y USUARIO.
Lo que quiero hacer es que cuando se ingrese al sistema dependiendo del usuario  esten habilitados algunos botones 
por ejemplo 
Si el usuario es administrador que esten habilitado todos los botones pero si es un usuario normal esten desabilitados todos

Este es el codigo donde valido los datos de los usuarios para poder entrar al sistema

```
<?php 
$usuario = $_POST['u'];
$pass= $_POST['p'];


if(empty($usuario) || empty($pass))
{
    header("Location: index.html");
    exit();
}

mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die("Error al conectar".mysql_error());

mysql_select_db('horarioescolar') or die("Serror al seleccionlar la base de datos".mysql_error());

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM usuarios where usuario = '".$usuarios."' and passw = '".$pass."'");

if($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    if(  $row['passw'] == $pass){
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['usuarios'] = $usuario;
        header("Location:contenido.php");
    }else{
        header("Location:inde.php");
        exit();
    }
}else{
    header("Location:inde.php");

    exit();
}
```

Comment: Sería mejor no mostrar dichos botones , con des habilitarlos no basta, por otra parte su código es altamente vulnerable ataques de Inyección SQL , puede revisar está [Pregunta como referencia](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18232/c%C3%B3mo-evitar-la-inyecci%C3%B3n-sql-en-php)

Comment: @Dev.Joel como seria para que no se muestren o si me puedes proporcionar algun ejemplo

Comment: Supongo que el botón que deseas deshabilitar se encuentra en `contenido.php`, pero no has mostrado tu código para ver como generas los datos y así darte un ejemplo más exacto.

Comment: Hola, es imposible ayudarte si usas mysql_connect ya que ya es obsoleto y fue removido de PHP, si quieres te puedo dar el ejemplo completo pero con MySqli o PDO, mejor PDO que es lo mas recomendable, mas seguro y mas rapido

Comment: @ByGroxD si me pudieras ayudar con el ejemplo de echo el mysql_connect  ya  lo estoy cambiando nomas que por el tiempo tuve que usar unos ejemplos que tenia

Comment: Te recomendaría utilizar PDO, aquí puedes echar un vistazo: http://php.net/manual/es/ref.pdo-mysql.php

Answer (score 1):

Respondiendo lo que pedis sería de esta forma (abajo está también COMO debe ser en realidad):

```
<input type="hidden" id="user_level" value="<?=$user_level?>"
```

(siendo $user_level una variable donde guardas que tipo de user es)

```
<button onclick="algunafuncionaejecutar();" id="funcion1">Acción 1</button>
<button onclick="otrafuncionaejecutar();" id="funcion2">Acción 2</button>
```

y tienes una función JS el cual se encarga de validar quien es (tendrás que editarla para que quede como lo necesites)...

```
validUSer: function () {
   if($('#user_level').val() == 'user_NO_admin') {
      $('#funcion1').prop('disabled', true);
      $('#funcion2').prop('disabled', true);
   }
},
```

================================
Ahora, una forma que te serviría si es una plataforma pequeña y queres poder discriminar bien acceso a donde pueden ir (vía menú), tenés esta opción:

```
switch ($user_level) {
    case 'administrador':
        require_once('cabecera_admin.php');
        break;
    case 'editor':
        require_once('cabecera_editor.php');
        break;
    case 'usuario':
        require_once('cabecera_usuario.php');
        break;
}
```

donde en base a $user_level (variable donde guardaste que tipo de usuario es) se le muestra un header con el menú de items habilitado exclusivamente según su nivel, puede ser también $_SESSION en vez de guardar como variable el tipo de usuario... Y cabe destacar (obviamente XD) que en cada sección que tengas en tu sitio, validez que tipo de persona es para que pueda usar el formulario (o lo que haya) o redirigirle si no tiene el nivel de user que corresponde...

===
Para manejar MySQL este es mi pequeño copiatín que suelo tener...
https://github.com/kuroinekowitch/MySQL-PDO-Syntax

(al cual hay que acompañarlo también siempre con varias medidas de limpieza de datos para mas seguridad...)

Answer (score 1):

Agregamos una variable de sesion con el tipo de usuario:

```
$_SESSION["tipo"] = $row['tipo_usuario'];
```

antes del redireccionamiento al contenido.php

```
<?php 
$usuario = $_POST['u'];
$pass= $_POST['p'];


if(empty($usuario) || empty($pass))
{
header("Location: index.html");
exit();
}

mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die("Error al conectar".mysql_error());

mysql_select_db('horarioescolar') or die("Serror al seleccionlar la base de datos".mysql_error());

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM usuarios where usuario = '".$usuarios."' and passw = '".$pass."'");

if($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
if(  $row['passw'] == $pass){
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['usuarios'] = $usuario;
// Agregamos una variable de sesion con el tipo de usuario
$_SESSION["tipo"] = $row['tipo_usuario'];

    header("Location:contenido.php");
}else{
    header("Location:inde.php");
    exit();
}
}else{
header("Location:inde.php");

exit();
}
```

y en contenido.php, le agregas un if al elemento que quieras

```
<? if ($_SESSION["tipo"]=="administrador")
{echo "Contenido exclusivo para usuario tipo Admin"; } 
?>
```